# How to bundle install a git gem behind a proxy?

Tags: ruby, git, proxy, rubygems, bundle

I am behind a proxy and I have a git gem in my Gemfile. How can I configure bundler to use git with the appropriate proxy parameters?

I already have $http_proxy appropriatelly set, as well as my .gemrc . Still, it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you get this working? I am stuck with exact same problem :(

Comment: Yes. I got this working, basically, you should use the http://... url instead of the git:// , and, of course, you should have the proxy properly configured for the http protocol. Ariejan's answer is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you are using git-over-http? I.e. does your git URL start with `http://`?

Answer (score 3):

1. Remember that setting http_proxy for your user wont be preserved when you execute sudo - to preserve it, do:

   ```
   sudo -E yourcommand
   ```

   I got my gem install working by first installing cntlm local proxy. The instructions here is succinct : http://www.leg.uct.ac.za/howtos/use-isa-proxies
2. Instead of student number, you'd put your domain username
3. To use the cntlm local proxy, exec:

   ```
   sudo gem install --http-proxy http://localhost:3128 theGem
   ```